# SELECT * faster than SELECT columnlist

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have a complicated view on a database which returns 26'404 rows by executing multiple joins on it (left and inner joins), including here some columns from sub-query.

I tried running two queries:

1)

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM dbo.vw_viewname as v
```

and

2)

```
SELECT 
v.column_name 
FROM dbo.vw_viewname as v
```

The first query execution time:  **0:00:40**

The second query execution time: **0:02:13**

The difference in time is even bigger when I call this view from a different Database, performing join from there **[0:00:02 VS 0:02:30]**. (yupp, 2 seconds vs 2 minutes)

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I really cannot find any logical reason!

***EDIT***: Including in SELECT list columns of view generated by sub-queries brings execution time to normal (2 seconds).

Comment: What does your execution plan show?

Comment: Which order? (Cold/hot data?)

Comment: It is happening because SQL Server is changing the execution plan, based on the columns being returned.  Why the performance gets worse it probably due to poor table statistics.  This is an unusual occurrence.

Comment: @alroc Almost absolutely the same thing. I mean no changes that would justify this difference

Comment: Definitely would concur with the thoughts on stats + different plans in the cache due to the statements being different.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/A9s8Aa7 - As I said, identical. If anyone has any reference on this happening to others, would be great if you could provide links

Comment: It's the remote query in the execution plan for which we need to see...the execution plan....